How to make a tilemap in pygame?
so I have some Python code to generate a random 10x10 grid in which a mine will be or won't be placed, I am having trouble trying to convert this list into a use-able set of coordinates. Any help would be appreciated

fieldx = 10
fieldy = 10
objecs = 20
    
Field = []
for i in range(fieldy):
  Field.append([])
  for j in range(fieldx):
    Field[i].append([0])



for i in range(objecs):
  x = random.randint(0,fieldx-1)
  y = random.randint(0,fieldy-1)
  if Field[y][x] == [0]:
    Field[y][x] = [1]


What do you find unusable about the coordinates you have?

I cant quite think of a way to turn the list created into a method of drawing items to the screen. what i want to happen is where the 1 in the list is, there should be an object created. otherwise it should be left blank
